# Getting a diverse set of three numbers from two numbers

Tags: functions, computer-science, coloring

I'm using this information to build an interface to pick a color, but I feel that this question is purely math-related. Please correct me if this is the wrong StackExchange site for this.

I am making a function that accepts two numbers, n and m. n is a number between 0 and 200 and m is a number between 0 and 100. I want this function to return a set of three numbers (x, y, z), each number between 0 and 255.

There are n*m (20,000) possible unique inputs to this function, but the output could be one of 255^3 (16,581,375) combinations of the three numbers. Because I am using these numbers to generate color, I want to ensure that there is as diverse a set of results as possible based on the input.

Basically, I want f(n, m) to represent a diverse range of the 255^3 three number outputs.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could construct a function that outputs three numbers based on the input of two numbers in this way?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Do you want the output to vary in a particular way based on one of the variables? That is, do you have any requirements for how $f(50,m)$ and $f(100,m)$ (for example) are related? Or are you just looking for any old function?

Comment: @rogerl: Ideally f(50, m) and f(51, m) are closer than f(50, m) and f(100, m) in order to show a gradual change of colors, but this isn't a hard requirement.

Comment: There are (of course) all sorts of ways. One would be: let $f(n,m) = \frac{100n+m}{100\cdot 200 + 100}\cdot 256^3$; then round the result and look at it as three two-digit hex numbers. I suspect that this isn't quite right at the ends of the range, but I'm sure you can play around with it.

Comment: Since you say you want numbers between 0 and 255, I'm guessing you might be using RGB color naming (or perhaps CIE's XYZ naming scheme). In that case, you've asked the wrong question, since a scattering that's uniform in RGB coordinates will be drastically perceptually nonuniform. You might want to look at LAB, or one of the other more perceptually uniform color coordinate systems.

Comment: @John: It looks like mapping x and y to hue and saturation from HSL with a fixed lightness is going to give me the best results. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, constraining the space to 2D makes it much easier.

Comment: You might want to consider mapping to $a$ and $b$ in Lab coordinates as well...just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(n + m x 200) x 838.8608` will give you `20000` numbers well spread out in the RGB space. Incrementing `n` will increase the green by two units and the blue by 71; incrementing `m` will increase the red by two or three units and green/blue by larger increments. In practice, you will see no correlation between (n, m) and the color.

Comment: You may have additional requirements that would lead to other formulas, but it is difficult to fill 3D space with a 2D surface.

Comment: Yes that is a good point! I was not able to point that out so clearly.

Comment: I was asking the wrong question, but I threw this formula in my color picker, and it *does* seem to put a great variety of color on the rectangle! It just seems to be a completely random order.

Comment: Yep, it fills the color cube uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

We have 20000 possible inputs, if we want to distribute these into the 3 channels we get $\sqrt[3]{20000} = 27.14...$ different values per channel. Now we just need a function

$$
f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3 \text{ with } f([1,100],[1,200]) = [1,27]^3
$$

But you cannot find a function that maps these two sets really smoothly into eachother.

I'd try for example $$f(x,y) = 256 \cdot \left (\frac{\left \lfloor \frac{x}{\sqrt{200}} \right\rfloor}{\sqrt{200}}, \frac{x-\sqrt{200}\left \lfloor \frac{x}{\sqrt{200}} \right\rfloor}{200},\frac{y}{100} \right)$$ (The three values should be rounded to integers after multiplication with 256. This function maps of course $[0,200] \times [0,100]$ to $[0,255]^3$)